# What scriptures shows that Jesus will still utterly save those who once professed trust in Jesus and yet lived in ungodliness?

Tags: contradiction, romans, soteriology, ephesians, pauline-epistles

Considering the following Scriptures:

Ephe 2:8, 9
8 For it is by grace you have been saved through faith, and this not from yourselves; it is the gift of God, 9 not by works, so that no one can boast.

Romans 10:9-12 - 9 If you declare with your mouth, “Jesus is Lord,” and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved.

Here we see that our salvation is totally on God's work for us. Not our work for us. This will mean that there is nothing we can do that will sabotage God's work for us.

However, the same Paul said:

Ephe 5:1-7
1 Be imitators of God, therefore, as beloved children, 2 and walk in love, just as Christ loved us a and gave Himself up for us as a fragrant sacrificial offering to God.

3 But among you, as is proper among the saints, there must not be even a hint of sexual immorality, or of any kind of impurity, or of greed. 4 Nor should there be obscenity, foolish talk, or crude joking, which are out of character, but rather thanksgiving. 5 For of this you can be sure: No immoral, impure, or greedy person (that is, an idolater), has any inheritance in the kingdom of Christ and of God.

6 Let no one deceive you with empty words, for because of such things the wrath of God is coming on the sons of disobedience. 7 Therefore do not be partakers with them.

This is saying that our conduct matters and God will not have in the Kingdom anyone who manifests the works of the Flesh.

Question:

How do we reconcile both scriptures, seeing that believers still sin and still walk in the flesh at times?

When we do not keep obeying the commandments of God, does it also sever one from being saved by the unconditional advocacy of Jesus?

Comment: I don't see anything to reconcile. Those who repent and believe the gospel and receive the indwelling of the Holy Spirit will walk in the Spirit and live holy lives. I cannot understand why you need to ask this question. Could you please add _clarification_ and _detail_ to support your enquiry.

Comment: So those who did not walk in the Spirit after receiving the Spirit we're not Saved at all?  Nice one.  I hope you were not the one that Voted my question to be closed? @NigelJ

Comment: @FaithMendel. Many believers may find themselves stuck in Romans six and seven, especially if they are under legalistic teaching where the burden of trying to live righteously is placed by looking to themselves to perform.  Those who have been called by God may look like total failures in living up to their new life in Christ.  It does take time to learn how to walk in the spirit and reckon the flesh dead.

Comment: @Sherrie So one who although have professed trust, in Jesus, but lives in Perpertual immorality will be saved ?

Comment: @Faith Mendel 1 Co. 5:9 -13 Deals with someone who is named as a brother who is caught up in immorality.  Nothing can ever touch his position before God in Christ. 1 Co. 6:9-11 states that they once were some of those things mentioned,  but that they were washed, they were sanctified,  they were justified in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ and by the spirit of our God.  God does not undo who he is in Christ.  Ephesians 5:5 is a repetition of 1Co. 6:9. None of those people have any allotment in God's kingdom or rule in the coming ages. These are the unjust.

Comment: Paul warns that same Brother.  And says otherwise. And even warns the church of people who teach otherwise.

Comment: "*This will mean that there is nothing we can do that will sabotage God's work for us.*" Why would you conclude that it means that?  ¶ My will leaves everything to my children; that was my decision to make, not theirs. There was nothing they did to deserve it; it is my gift to them. Nothing anyone other than they can do anything to earn it; they aren't my children. — Can one conclude from those statements that there is nothing any of my children can do that would cause me to disinherit them? No, that would be poor reasoning. They could; and I would.

Comment: @FaithMendel I hope you didn't mind, I edited the Q - please undo if not happy with the edit.  Good Q, re-open - seems like a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Bible, we *are* saved by works, but not by our works--we are saved by the work of Christ in our behalf.  No one can possibly merit salvation by his or her own works.  This is why the Bible says we are saved by grace, and not by works--salvation is a free gift that we cannot earn.

However, in order to receive the free gift, we must have faith.

> But without faith it is impossible to please him: for he that cometh
> to God must believe that he is, and that he is a rewarder of them that
> diligently seek him. (Hebrews 11:6, KJV)

And faith is non-existent (dead) without works.

> <sup>15</sup> If a brother or sister be naked, and destitute of daily
> food, <sup>16</sup> And one of you say unto them, Depart in peace, be
> ye warmed and filled; notwithstanding ye give them not those things
> which are needful to the body; what doth it profit? <sup>17</sup> Even
> so **faith, if it hath not works, is dead,** being alone. (James 2:15-17,
> KJV)

To illustrate this kind of faith, James provides Abraham as an example.

> <sup>21</sup> Was not Abraham our father justified by works, when he
> had offered Isaac his son upon the altar? <sup>22</sup> Seest thou how
> faith wrought with his works, and by works was faith made perfect?
> <sup>23</sup> And the scripture was fulfilled which saith, Abraham
> believed God, and it was imputed unto him for righteousness: and he
> was called the Friend of God. <sup>24</sup> Ye see then how that by
> works a man is justified, and not by faith only. (James 2:21-24, KJV)

Imagine what we might think of Abraham if we learned that he was a thief, or an idolator, or obscene, or greedy, etc.  Would we consider him to be one who really loved God, and was "the Friend of God"?

Another Biblical example would be Judas.  He was one of Jesus' own disciples, and professed to love and serve him.  Yet in the end, he made the fatal decision to betray Jesus.  The Bible solemnly records his fate.  Jesus himself indicates, during his prayer for the disciples, that Judas was to be lost.

> While I was with them in the world, I kept them in thy name: those
> that thou gavest me I have kept, **and none of them is lost, but the
> son of perdition;** that the scripture might be fulfilled. (John
> 17:12, KJV)

Jesus asks for our love, and that we show our love by keeping his commandments.

> If ye love me, keep my commandments. (John 14:15, KJV)
>
> Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my
> words: and my Father will love him, and we will come unto him, and
> make our abode with him. (John 14:23, KJV)

Those who do not love God enough to put their beliefs into action will be among those of whom Jesus said:

> This people draweth nigh unto me with their mouth, and honoureth me
> with their lips; but their heart is far from me. (Matthew 15:8, KJV)

God looks at our heart.

> But the LORD said unto Samuel, Look not on his countenance, or on the
> height of his stature; because I have refused him: for the LORD seeth
> not as man seeth; for man looketh on the outward appearance, but **the
> LORD looketh on the heart.** (1 Samuel 16:7, KJV)

Where is your heart?  Whom do you love most?  Of whom do you most desire to speak?  Whom do you serve?

As the old adage says: "Actions speak louder than words."

No one will be saved by their works--but no one will be saved without works, either, for our works are the earnest of our faith.  Those who finally turn away, as did Judas, will be lost, as was Judas.

Comment: Good answer - Eze 18 supports your conclusion. +1.